# HTML5 <video> on Android has poster image with top margin

Tags: android, css, html, video, webview

I have a poster image on a video that is shifted down about 40 pixels leaving whitespace above it. When the video plays it moves up and plays in its correct location. Also, the control bar centers vertically on the video instead of aligning at the bottom of the video.

This video is being rendered in an Android WebView. Works fine on all other browsers without the fantom margin or odd control placement.

I'm wondering if any of my css could be throwing it off (When I check the computed values in Safari Web Inspector both padding and margin are 0)

[image: The video should be flush with the hairline divider]

Above the video poster image can be seen with the fantom margin. The poster image should be flush with the hairline divider.

[image: You can see the video controls are incorrectly centered vertically]

I believe the above issue is related, the video controls are centered vertically on the video when they should sit at the bottom. You can see that the video has shifted up in that margin.

[image: The controls eventually fade away and the video plays fine]

Eventually the controls fade away and the video plays as it should.

Is there any way to apply css directly to a video poster? I'm guessing the poster is displaying awkwardly because it is a different size than the video. I'm wondering what CSS I'd need to handle this.

My CSS foo is not that great. I'm more a native developer.

Answer (score 1):

This was a problem with my CSS. Eventually I had to wrap everything in a div an put height and width to 100%

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle with the solution? I am having the same issue.